# Why Does My Website Redirect me to my localhost?

Tags: web, localhost

Alright, my website has some issues that I'm not sure what's causing them. Visit this page http://online-file-sharing.net/tos.html and click one of the bottom footer links... it redirects you to your localhost in the address bar. I have no idea why it does this. I'm hosting this website on my own server, which is this computer, and using Xampp. If this information helps. Anyways any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm also using DYNDNS as my nameservers.

I've already ask this question on superuser and webapps QnA sites neither could help. They said to come here. Another thing to note is that this website runs on one script and not multiple scripts (upload.cgi). However there are three files that aren't dynamic and aren't part of the upload.cgi file... these are about.html, browse.html and tos.html.

Another thing to note is that my homepage which is upload.cgi can only be accessed by manually typing in online-file-sharing.net/cgi-bin/upload.cgi (which isn't it's real location but it seems to recognize it this way... but redirects me to my localhost).

**.htaccess file code:**

```
DirectoryIndex upload.cgi
```

**My upload.cgi path code:**

```
my $version = "4.14";
$ENV{PATH} = '/bin:/usr/bin';
delete @ENV{'IFS', 'CDPATH', 'ENV', 'BASH_ENV'};
($ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT}) = ($ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT} =~ /(.*)/); # untaint.
#$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME} = '/cgi-bin/upload.cgi';
use lib './perlmodules';
#use Time::HiRes 'gettimeofday';
#my $hires_start = gettimeofday();
my (%PREF,%TEXT) = ();
```

The script I'm using is FileChucker.

I hope this information is enough to find an answer... if not please let me know and I'll post as much information as you need!

Comment: it's not a redirect, the link says http://localhost/...

Comment: Yes, I know that... we've already established this. I'm triyng to figure out how to fix the issue of my upload.cgi script now. It's location is in the root directory but is only accessible by accessing it with this URL: http://online-file-sharing.net/upload.cgi but what even weirder I can conenct to it perfectly with it's IP.

Answer (score 3):

Your footer links are:

```
<a href="http://localhost/">Home</a> &#8211; 
<a href="http://localhost/filechucker.cgi?action=listfiles">Download Files</a> - 
<a href="#">TOS</a>
```

which point to localhost, so it's doing exactly what you told it to do.

For your `upload.cgi`, the headers I get back are:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 26 Dec 2010 02:39:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
Location: http://localhost/?&number_of_files=0&ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&host=&duration=2 seconds&act=upload_result
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

Notice the `Location: http://localhost/...` in there, which redirects the browser to localhost.

Comment: Yes I know... but try http://online-file-sharing.net/cgi-bin/upload.cgi and see where that leads you... to your localhost. I have no idea why.

Comment: Have any ideas why this does it to?

Comment: Would this HTTP 302 not found error have to do with my above upload.cgi paths/directories?

Comment: That's clearly not your complete `upload.cgi` script, so it's impossible for me to say why it's returning that redirect.

Comment: Did you write this script, or did you get it from somewhere else? Could you look through the script to see where it returns a "Status: 302" line?

Comment: I bought it. It's called FileChucker. I did a search for the string "Status: 302" and it didn't show up any results.

Comment: A quick look at [the documentation](http://encodable.com/filechucker/faq/#config) shows that you may need to edit some files such as "filechucker_prefs.cgi". Since you bought the product, your first line of support should probably be the company itself (yes, I understand they might not be answering support email today). As for Skype, I would prefer to keep this dialogue here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I've edited the filechucker_prefs.cgi file. It's not the problem. In fact, the entire script works fine with my Internet IP address but when I try it with my domain name everything is screwed up. I also just registered this domain name and used DYNDNS as my Custom DNS service provider. Could this play any effect on the problems I'm receiving?

Comment: I just tried the script with your IP address instead of the domain name, and I still get the same redirect response (not sure why you would be observing different behaviour). The problem you're having is likely related to the script or configuration itself, rather than DynDNS (it appears that is all working ok). I'm not sure how much more help I can be without knowing more about this particular script, so perhaps you could look for a support forum of some kind. It's getting beyond my ability to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened your site and checked that *url* in *href* is localhost. So it could be you are running any kind of development server and is running under localhost? The server my be thinking it's name is localhost!